# Line breaks in IMAP - =\r\n - how to decode?

Tags: python, email, decode, decoding, imaplib

I am trying to make an email scraper that scrapes through certain emails looking for values to store them in a CSV file. I have been trying a lot of things to get this problem solved but without success so far.

```
# Function to get email content part i.e its body part
def get_body(msg):
    if msg.is_multipart():
        return get_body(msg.get_payload(decode=True)).decode()
    else:
        return msg.get_payload(decode=True).decode()
 
# Function to search for a key value pair
def search(key, value, con):
    result, data = con.search(None, key, '"{}"'.format(value))
    return data
 
# Function to get the list of emails under this label
def get_emails(result_bytes):
    print("get email")
    msgs = [] # all the email data are pushed inside an array
    for num in result_bytes[0].split():
        typ, data = con.fetch(num, '(RFC822)')
        msgs.append(data)
    return msgs
 
# this is done to make SSL connection with GMAIL
con = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(imap_url)
con.login(user, password)
con.select('Inbox')
msg_ids = get_emails(search('SUBJECT', 'TESTTITELPYTHON', con))
for msg in msg_ids[::-1]:
    for sent in msg:
        if type(sent) is tuple:
            print(msg)
            # encoding set as utf-8
            content = sent[1], 'utf-8'
            data = str(content)
 
            # Handling errors related to unicodenecode
            try:
                indexstart = data.find("span")
                data2 = data[indexstart + 5: len(data)]
                indexend = data2.find("</div>")
 
                # printtng the required content which we need
                # to extract from our email i.e our body
                
                waarde = data2[0: indexend]
                test_naam_1 = waarde.split("Naam: ",1)[1]
                echte_naam = test_naam_1.split("Email: ",-1)[0]
            
                email_test = waarde.split("Email: ",1)[1]
                echte_email = email_test.split("Tel nr.: ",-1)[0]
                                    
                tel_test = waarde.split("Tel nr.: ",1)[1]
                echte_tel = tel_test.split("Onderwerp: ",-1)[0]
            
                subj_test = waarde.split("Onderwerp: ",1)[1]
                echte_subj = subj_test.split("Bericht: ",-1)[0]


                print("---ADRESGEGEVENS---")
                print("---Naam: " + echte_naam + "---")
                print("---Naam: " + echte_email + "---")
                print("---Naam: " + echte_tel + "---")
                print("---Naam: " + echte_subj + "---")
```

Now in my results I am still receiving these ugly line breaks which look as following in my markup:

```
[(b'12638 (RFC822 {1973}', b'MIME-Version: 1.0\r\nDate: Mon, 25 Oct 2021 16:41:46 +0200\r\nMessage-ID: <CAJDn=xsVynQqp7BwYoGZB=v21-AAR5=xcMkQ8D2kXE7ZpYFNNQ@mail.example.com>\r\nSubject: TESTTITELPYTHON\r\nFrom: Patrick Merkx <patrick@example.nl>\r\nTo: Patrick Merkx <patrick@example.nl>\r\nContent-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="00000000000042e6ae05cf2e5c7e"\r\n\r\n--00000000000042e6ae05cf2e5c7e\r\nContent-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"\r\n\r\nContactformulier ingevuld door:\r\nNaam: Patrick Merkx\r\nEmail: merkx.patrick@example.com\r\nTel nr.: 0611381219\r\n\r\nOnderwerp: Nog een test\r\n\r\nBericht:\r\nBericht\r\n\r\n--00000000000042e6ae05cf2e5c7e\r\nContent-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable\r\n\r\n<div dir=3D"ltr"><div><div dir=3D"ltr" class=3D"gmail_signature" data-smart=\r\nmail=3D"gmail_signature"><div dir=3D"ltr"><div><div dir=3D"ltr"><div><div d=\r\nir=3D"ltr"><div style=3D"font-stretch:normal;font-size:13.33px;line-height:=\r\n19.99px;background:none;border:0px rgb(34,34,34);width:600px;overflow:visib=\r\nle;min-height:0px;outline-width:0px"><span class=3D"gmail-il" style=3D"font=\r\n-size:small">Contactformulier</span><span style=3D"font-size:small">=C2=A0i=\r\nngevuld door:</span><br style=3D"font-size:small"><span style=3D"font-size:=\r\nsmall">Naam: Patrick Merkx</span><br style=3D"font-size:small"><span style=\r\n=3D"font-size:small">Email:=C2=A0</span><a href=3D"mailto:merkx.patrick@gma=\r\nil.com" target=3D"_blank" style=3D"font-size:small">merkx.patrick@example.com=\r\n</a><br style=3D"font-size:small"><span style=3D"font-size:small">Tel nr.: =\r\n0611381219</span><br style=3D"font-size:small"><br style=3D"font-size:small=\r\n"><span style=3D"font-size:small">Onderwerp: Nog een test</span><br style=\r\n=3D"font-size:small"><br style=3D"font-size:small"><span style=3D"font-size=\r\n:small">Bericht:</span><br style=3D"font-size:small"><span style=3D"font-si=\r\nze:small">Bericht</span><br></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div=\r\n></div>\r\n\r\n--00000000000042e6ae05cf2e5c7e--'), b')']
class=3D"gmail-il" style=3D"font=\r\n-size:small">Contactformulier</span><span style=3D"font-size:small">=C2=A0i=\r\nngevuld door:</span><br style=3D"font-size:small"><span style=3D"font-size:=\r\nsmall">Naam: Patrick Merkx</span><br style=3D"font-size:small"><span style=\r\n=3D"font-size:small">Email:=C2=A0</span><a href=3D"mailto:merkx.patrick@gma=\r\nil.com" target=3D"_blank" style=3D"font-size:small">merkx.patrick@gmail.com=\r\n</a><br style=3D"font-size:small"><span style=3D"font-size:small">Tel nr.: =\r\n0611381219</span><br style=3D"font-size:small"><br style=3D"font-size:small=\r\n"><span style=3D"font-size:small">Onderwerp: Nog een test</span><br style=\r\n=3D"font-size:small"><br style=3D"font-size:small"><span style=3D"font-size=\r\n:small">Bericht:</span><br style=3D"font-size:small"><span style=3D"font-si=\r\nze:small">Bericht</span><br>
```

I have also tried stripping the body tag, decoding and have also been trying multiple solutions but unlucky so far. I can't seem to get these line breaks removed in any so far known way.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the expected result? the current result looks good to me

Comment: I want the data without the =\r\n tags so I can extract the values from the emails. (sometimes the lines get broken in the middle of the email where it will display an email like: thisistheemail@gmai=\r\nl.com)

Comment: There are also tags between the string like "=0D=0A=09=09" and "=0D=0A" which I also want removed / stripped out of the data. When you strip the HTML the data looks as following: "3D"2">=0D=0A=09=09                                =\r\n        Naam=0D=0A=09=09                                    =0D=0A=09=09                               =0D=0A=09=09         =\r\n                      =0D=0A=09=09             =\r\n   "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking at a MIME part with `Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable`.  The proper way to decode that is to traverse the MIME structure and interpret the parts as you go.  But there is no need to do that explicitly; Python's `email` library already does exactly that for you.

```py
from email import message_from_bytes
from email.policy import default

...
msg_ids = get_emails(search('SUBJECT', 'TESTTITELPYTHON', con))
for msg in msg_ids[::-1]:
    for sent in msg:
        if type(sent) is tuple:
            msg = message_from_bytes(sent[1], policy=default)
```

Unfortunately, without examples of the MIME structures in these messages, I can't tell you exactly how to process the resulting message. Probably you have something like a "primary" MIME body part; `msg.get_body(preferencelist=('html', 'plain'))` would pull that out, and `get_content()` on the result would extract the actual body part.

The `policy=default` keyword argument selects the `email.message.EmailMessage` object class which was introduced in Python 3.6 over the legacy `email.message.Message` object from older versions.

In some more detail, trying to decode raw email bodies as UTF-8 is *very* wrong. A typical MIME message has several parts, each of which might have a different encoding, and many of which certainly do not use UTF-8 as their encoding (though it's becoming more prevalent; but then, typically, the actual UTF-8 will be behind a content transfer encoding which shields it from damage during transport over routes which may not be 8-bit clean).

Comment: This is a great answer.  There’s a severe lack of examples of how to do this in the modern python libraries and this is a great how-to for future “how do I find/parse the body” questions.